# Can i upgrade my firmware with another phone model's official rom (using odin)?

Tags: rooting, rom-flashing, custom-roms, odin

Is it possible to upgrade my phone's firmware using another phone model's official rom using odin ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, Official or custom firmware are only to be used with the device specified in its name

Using a different phone model may result in your hard bricking your phone

Is there a reason why you want to use a different phone model firmware over your own?

Comment: My phone has android 4.1 os. I want to upgrade to 4.2. It is already rooted. But I can't find any custom rom for my mob . I am using samsung galaxy core.

Comment: From digging around a bit its unlikely that a 4.2 release will be made available, with regards to custom rom's there are many of XDA website under your phone, however getting 4.2 specifically may be hard as there are 4.4 released available

Comment: Ok.. can you suggest me a trustworthy website for downloading custom rom for my phone ? without any bugs ..

Comment: As mentioned above XDA Website would be your best bet, [link](http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-core/development)

With regards to the suggesting what custom rom its all down to personal preference. With regards to bugs look at what people have been commenting about the custom roms on the page. And as always doing this is at your own risk, no one can be held responsible and its always advised to create a full Nandroid backup before attempting to flash a rom

Answer (score 1):

Even if some apks would eventually work; device drivers, kernel, HAL would be for different peripherals. So, it would be useless and unsuccessful.